# In TortoiseHg, how can i "Merge local with selected"?

Tags: mercurial, merge, tortoisehg

In effect, I would like to do the opposite of "Merge with local"

To clarify:
We have a *release* branch and a *default* branch. When doing bug fixes on the release branch, here's the routine:

1. Update to the *release* branch
2. Implement bug fix, and commit
3. Update to the *default* branch
4. Right-click on the bug fix commit from the *release* branch, and select "Merge with local..."

Since a lot of work is done on the *release* branch, it gets tedious to Update between the branches all the time. In previous versions of TortoiseHg, I could select the branch before doing the merge, in effect doing a "Merge local with selected". This would eliminate steps 1 and 3 above.

Is this doable in TortoiseHg anymore?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Three-way merges are basically symmetric: you merge two divergent versions of your code (the two branches) into a single version (the merge commit). There is no technical different between updating to `default` and merging with `release`, or doing it the other way around. In particular, the merge conflicts are exactly the same.

In Mercurial, there is an extra twist because of the named branch names: by default, the merge commit will inherit the branch name of its *first* parent. If you don't update to `default` before merging, the first parent will thus be `release`. But you can **change the branch name** before committing.

On the command line it's just:

```
$ hg update release
$ hg merge default
$ hg branch default
$ hg commit -m 'Merged release into default'
```

In the pre-2.0 versions of TortoiseHg you were presented with this dialog to commit the merge:

[image: hgtk commit dialog]

The button above the commit message saying "branch: release" could be used to change branch of the next commit — the merge commit. In TortoiseHg 2.x the dialog looks like this:

[image: thg commit dialog]

and there's no longer a button for changing branch.

Maybe you can ask the TortoiseHg developers to add the button again, or you can use [Henrik Stuart's TortoiseHg](https://bitbucket.org/hstuart/hgtk) if you want a pre-2.0 TortoiseHg that is compatible with modern versions of Mercurial.

Comment: Interesting!  And it can be done in post-2.0 by cancelling the merge commit, then using the normal commit process to commit the merge on a different branch.

Comment: @MarkTolonen: ah, clever! I didn't think of cancelling the dialog box.

Comment: This issue is now reported on https://bitbucket.org/tortoisehg/thg/issue/1831/missing-the-ability-to-change-branch-name

Answer (score 1):

I haven't found a way, even command line merge is always with local.  I just keep a clone for each branch and switch between clones instead of updating a single clone.  For large projects this prevents the usually time-intensive "rebuild all" when changing branches.  Adds extra pull step but saves time overall:

1. In *release* clone, implement bug fix and commit.
2. In *default* clone, pull from *release* and merge with local.